# No puedo comprobar header HMAC del webhook

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, headers, webhook

Tengo una función en google cloud la cual recibe un webhook de cierta página. Dicho webhook tiene un header personalizado por la pagina de origen, lo llamaré `myHeader` por fines privados, entonces en la página dice

> The endpoint receiving the payload must validate the payload by checking that the HTTP header myHeader of the callback matches the HMAC256 of the secret on the payload's body bytes.

Entonces estoy tratando de hacer coincidir el header con lo que me devuelva `hmac.new()` pero el `hmac.compare_digested()` siempre me devuelve false, y pues obviamente, las salidas nunca coinciden con el header

```
import base64
import json
import hmac, hashlib

def webhook(request):
  if request.method != 'POST':
    print('Is not POST')
    return {
      'StatusCode': 403,
      'StatusMessage': 'Not correct method'
    }
  try:
    request_json = request.get_json()
    userInfo = '<Secret_from_Origin>'#Codigo obtenido desde el origen
    access_token = str(request.headers['myHeader'])
    print('Header',access_token)
    print('Secret',userInfo['sk'])
    if not verify(userInfo.encode(), json.dumps(request_json).encode(), access_token):
      print('User not allow')
      return {
        'StatusCode': 403,
        'StatusMessage': 'User not allow'
      }
    print('Signature validate!')
  return {
    'StatusCode': 200,
    'StatusMessage': 'Webhook valid!'
  }

def verify(api_key, request_body_string, expected_signature):
  hmac_digest = "sha256=" + hmac.new(api_key,
                          request_body_string,
                          digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
  print('Digested', hmac_digest)
  return hmac.compare_digest(str(expected_signature), str(hmac_digest))
```

[Fuente](https://developers.hint.com/docs/webhooks). Entonces que me falta o estoy haciendo mal?? Llevo ya una semana tratando de comprobar este header pero nisiquiera en la propia comunidad de la pagina responde nadie. Alguien puede ayudarme con este problema??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventualmente estaba haciendo algo mal... Y es que en la linea de `request_json = request.get_json()` no era `.get_json()` si no que es `.get_data()` de esta forma obtengo rawData, en algunos tutoriales, donde la información está a quema ropa, natural en bytes, por lo que al enviarla al método `verify()` solo envio lo que tengo, ya sin necesidad de codificar o algo así. Quedando mi condición de la siguiente manera

```
if not verify(userInfo.encode(), request.get_data(), access_token)
```